# Output the multiple of ten a number is in. python

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to make a number guessing game and I am trying to code in hints. 
For the hints I would like it to output the multiple of ten the number is in because I am having quite big ranges of the numbers.
For example say the number is 394 I want the program to output that the number is between 390 and 400 in a message box.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?! If you keep the code you tried it would be easy and helpful for everyone while answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer dividing:

```
print "Number is between {} , {}".format((num // 10) * 10, (num // 10 + 1) * 10)
```